# Conditional Shape/Color plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
categories <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
trends <- c(.20, -.05, 0, .1, 0)

df <- as.data.frame(categories, trends)
```

I'm trying to create a plot that has green triangles for positive trends, red triangles for negative trends, and black squares for zero trends.

This is my attempt, but the colors and guide are not coming out right.

```
ggplot(
  df %>%
    mutate(color_index = ifelse(trends > 0, "green", 
                         ifelse(trends < 0, "red", "black")),
           shape_id = ifelse(trends > 0, 24, 
                      ifelse(trends < 0, 25, 22))),

  aes(x = categories, y = trends, fill = color_index)) +

  # up/down arrow points
  geom_point(aes(shape = shape_id), size = 7) +
  scale_shape_identity() +
  geom_text(aes(label=trends*100), size = 4, nudge_y=-0.01, check_overlap = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `scale_fill_identity` to your plot

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = categories, y = trends, fill = color_index)) +
  # up/down arrow points
  geom_point(aes(shape = shape_id), size = 7) +
  scale_shape_identity() +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  geom_text(aes(label=trends*100), size = 4, nudge_y=-0.01, check_overlap = TRUE)
```

[image]

**data**

```
categories <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
trends <- c(.20, -.05, 0, .1, 0)

df <- data.frame(categories, trends)
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(color_index = ifelse(trends > 0, "green", 
                              ifelse(trends < 0, "red", "black")),
         shape_id = ifelse(trends > 0, 24, 
                           ifelse(trends < 0, 25, 22)))
```